# CSS - 100% width on hover, despite setting the element to a different width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with CSS.
I centered all and it works properly but there is a problem with the hover css.
When I set active class or hover li element the background color is set to 100%.
Also the parapraph starts from the left side and is not exacly under the element.
I try inspect code but I don't see anything there.

What's the reason and how to avoid somethig like that in the future??

[image: Screen]

I want to get something like that:
[image]

I tried to preview the code and change widths and other classes

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #009add;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-512/free-search-1779499-1513194.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  outline: none;
  border-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px var(--main-color);
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.accordion {
  /* background-color: #eee; */
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  /* width: 100%; */
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: var(--main-color);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Najczęściej zadawanie pytania:</h2>

  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Wyszukaj.." title="Wyszukaj">
  </div>
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li class="accordion"><a href="#">TYTUŁ</a></li>
    </id>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Rozwiązanie</p>
    </div>
    <li class="accordion"><a href="#">TYTUŁ2</a></li>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Rozwiązanie</p>
    </div>
  </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want there to be a slight border around that I can define myself, and a paragraph to be directly under the 'Title' and not starting from the beginning of the page.

Comment: I think you mean to set the `<li>` element to a width of 90%, but instead you've reduced the width of the `<a>` element inside it to 90%.

Comment: If i remove width from <a> then element is shorter but the blue hover still exists.
Adding width into <li> element does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix some of your code. The thing was that the active hue was from the background and not the border which is the common thing to do in CSS.

Not the cleanest code in the planet, there's a lot to simplify, but hey, I think you might like it!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        :root {
            --main-color: #009add;
        }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Century Gothic';

        }

        h2 {
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #myInput {
            background-image: url('https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-512/free-search-1779499-1513194.png');
            background-size: contain;
            background-position: 0;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            width: 50%;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            outline: none;
            border-style: none;
            margin-bottom: 12px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px var(--main-color);
        }

        #myUL {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            border-radius: 20px;
        }

        #myUL li {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-top: -1px;
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            padding: 12px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: black;
            border-radius: 20px;
            display: block;
        }
        
        #myUL li:hover {
            border: 1px solid var(--main-color);
        }

        .accordion {
            /* background-color: #eee; */
            color: #444;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 5px;
            /* width: 100%; */
            text-align: left;
            outline: none;
            font-size: 15px;
            transition: 0.4s;
            border-radius: 20px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        
        #myUL .active {
            border: 1px solid var(--main-color);
        }

        .panel {
            padding: 0 18px;
            display: none;
            background-color: white;
            color: var(--main-color);
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>Najczęściej zadawanie pytania:</h2>

    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Wyszukaj.." title="Wyszukaj">
    </div>
    <ul id="myUL">
        <li class="accordion"><a href="#">TYTUŁ</a></li>
        </id>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Rozwiązanie</p>
        </div>
        <li class="accordion"><a href="#">TYTUŁ2</a></li>
        <div class="panel">
            <p>Rozwiązanie</p>
        </div>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
            ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
            li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
            for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
                a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
                txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
                if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                    li[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    li[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }

        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (panel.style.display === "block") {
                    panel.style.display = "none";
                } else {
                    panel.style.display = "block";
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks great, The UI will be changed so don't worry how it looks right now 
But now this is also one problem.
This elements are not centered and if I add Display Flex then again destroys everything.

Comment: Checkout the last edit. No need to add width to `#myUL li` 

Comment: This solved my problems. I modified a bit but now it's working properly.
Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear! Feel free to edit my answer. 

Answer (score 1):

you can change you .panel class like this

```
.panel {
   padding: 0 18px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 90%;
   display: none;
   background-color: white;
   color: var(--main-color);
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
:root {
  --main-color: #009add;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic';
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-512/free-search-1779499-1513194.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  outline: none;
  border-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px var(--main-color);
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
}

#myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.accordion {
  /* background-color: #eee; */
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  /* width: 100%; */
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: var(--main-color);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h2>Najczęściej zadawanie pytania:</h2>

  <div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Wyszukaj.." title="Wyszukaj">
  </div>
  <ul id="myUL">
    <li class="accordion"><a href="#">TYTUŁ</a></li>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Rozwiązanie</p>
    </div>
    <li class="accordion"><a href="#">TYTUŁ2</a></li>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Rozwiązanie</p>
    </div>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This solved paragraph alignment but there is still problem with hover one.
I saw that if I uncomment background-color then this size is seen but I can't resize that.